# KWP fast protocol via CAN bus for OBD2

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii

I have a question about my CAR's ODB function.
I have a USB dongle with AT90CAN128 uE , the uE has CAN driver and i can use this to read the data traffic on the bus.
I have a BMW 116i but this car uses KWP-fast protocol for the obd2.
I want to ask if can i use the CAN bus to send queries to the ECU for the obd2 available variables. 
I am not sure because at work we use the KWP2000 protocol via CAN bus, but i don't have the specification, we use a ready tool on CANoe.

Answer (score 0):

KWP2000 is not CAN, they are completly different. OBD2 includes CAN and KWP2000 (also J1850, among others). They use a different physical layer and you won't be able to use CAN to listen/talk KWP2000.